# Why I get error when I try to generate ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this HtmlHelper:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.LayoutID, "someAction");
    </td>        
</tr>
}
```

On this row,

```
@Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.LayoutID, "someAction");
```

i get this error:

```
CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

Why do I get the above error ?
The LayoutID is of string type.

**EDIT**
Improved Formatting

Comment: Try this: `@Html.ActionLink(item.LayoutID, "someAction")`

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `ActionLink` method has to be a `string` which will appear as the anchor tag text. You are trying to pass a lamda expression.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td> @Html.ActionLink(item.LayoutID, "someAction") </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use modelitem as parameter in actionlink.actionlink must have string value as parameter 
try below code:

```
   @Html.ActionLink(item.LayoutID, "someAction")
```

or i will suggest you to direct write down string

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Report", "someAction")
```